# Getting a count of timestamps that fall into each 5 minute bucket

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table of timestamps. I'd like to group them into 5 minute buckets and get the count of timestamps in that bucket. I having some trouble getting the SQL quite right. I am using Postgres. It's telling me the timestamp column in the last line doesn't exist, but it's defined as an alias.

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +
    INTERVAL '1 second' * round(extract('epoch' from my_timestamp) / 300) * 300
    as timestamp,
    count(my_timestamp)
FROM logs
GROUP BY
round(extract('epoch' from timestamp) / 300)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `GROUP BY` is off.  Try this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + INTERVAL '1 second' * round(extract('epoch' from my_timestamp) / 300) * 300 as timestamp,
       count(*)
FROM (values (now())) logs(my_timestamp)
GROUP BY timestamp
```

Comment: that only returns a single entry with the current timestamp of now() with a count of 1

Comment: @user2242044 I think he just proposed that as a sample due to your case(not an exact match with your table, i.e. it works so your code works as this). Important thing is to include the alias in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user2242044 . . . This query demonstrates that the code works.  You can run the logic on your table.